# Convert JSON string UTF8 to NSDictionary Swift

Tags: json, swift, utf-8, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I want convert from JSON string to NSDictionary and data is UTF8.
This is my code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let string = "{\"name\":\"Việt NAM\",\"data\":{\"capital\":\"HÀ NỘI\",\"continents\":\"Châu Á\"}}"
    let dataResult = convertStringToDictionary(text: string)
    print (dataResult)
}



func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

And data print:

```
Optional(["name": Việt NAM, "data": {
capital = "H\U00c0 N\U1ed8I";
continents = "Ch\U00e2u \U00c1";}])
```

Data in AnyObject is not UTF8.

Comment: try [String:Any] convert data

Comment: There is no problem, that is just now the dictionary is printed. If you access the actual dictionary values then everything will be as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because you try to print dictionary's data directly rather than access it to its `key/value` first try to print all dictionary keys to get and see all keys.

```
print(parseJSON.allKeys)
```

it gives you for example these keys : `[name,data]`

then you can print any key's value you like :

`print("Name: \(parseJSON.value(forKey: "name") as! String)")`